# Filter layer by pasting in WHERE clause?

Tags: filter, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal, definition-query, where-clause

I have a web map in [Portal](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/what-is-portal-for-arcgis-.htm) that has the [Web AppBuilder Filter widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-filter.htm).

The map has a point layer in it called Work Orders.

[image]

I would like to filter the work orders by **pasting in a WHERE clause**.

- The WHERE clause is [generated](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.0/com.ibm.mt.doc/gp_ui/c_SQL_search.html) in a separate [work order management system](https://www.ibm.com/ca-en/marketplace/maximo).
- Example: `((woclass = 'WORKORDER' or woclass = 'ACTIVITY') 
  and contains(description,'$sidewalk') > 0  and historyflag = 0 and 
  istask = 0 and siteid = 'SERVICES')`

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Web AppBuilder add the Attribute Table widget and configure it by adding the layers you need. Then when you launch your web application expand the Attribute Table; there should be a Filter tool available under the Options tab. Using the Filter tool you should be able to apply your WHERE clause. The results of the filter will be highlighted in the map and the attribute table will be updated to just show those results. You can even export the results of the attribute table to a CSV file from the options tab.

Comment: I had played around with a custom widget to solve this. But your solution is out-of-the-box, which is great.